# Is it possible to have a ComboBox DisplayMember set to a property of an object in a list?

Tags: c#, list, winforms, combobox

I have a ComboBox being populated where each object in ComboBox.Items is a List of objects. Currently the ComboBox displays "(Collection)" for each Item.

Is it possible to have the ComboBox display a member of the first object in the List that comprises an Item of the ComboBox?

I am currently populating the ComboBox items by the following:

```cs
foreach(List<SorterIdentifier> sorterGroup in m_AvailableSorterGroups)
{
    // There are conditions that may result in the sorterGroup not being added
    comboBoxSorterSelect.Items.Add(sorterGroup);
}

//comboBoxSorterSelect.DataSource = m_AvailableSorterGroups; // Not desired due to the comment above.
//comboBoxSorterSelect.DisplayMember = "Count"; //Displays the Count of each list.
```

The value that I would like to have displayed in the ComboBox can be referenced with:

```cs
((List<SorterIdentifier>)comboBoxSorterSelect.Items[0])[0].ToString();
((List<SorterIdentifier>)comboBoxSorterSelect.Items[0])[0].DisplayName; // public member
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an object wrapper and override the `ToString()` method:

```
public class ComboBoxSorterIdentifierItem
{

  public List<SorterIdentifier> Items { get; }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    if ( Items == null || Items.Count == 0) return "";
    return Items[0].ToString();
  }

  public BookItem(List<SorterIdentifier> items)
  {
    Items = items;
  }

}
```

You should override the `SorterIdentifier.ToString()` too to return what you want like `DisplayName`.

Now you can add items in the combobox like this:

```
foreach(var sorterGroup in m_AvailableSorterGroups)
{
  item = new ComboBoxSorterIdentifierItem(sorterGroup);
  comboBoxSorterSelect.Items.Add(item);
}
```

And to use the selected item for example, you can write:

```
... ((ComboBoxSorterIdentifierItem)comboBoxSorterSelect.SelectedItem).Item ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I could imagine a few ways to do this... you could create a class that extends `List<T>`, so you have an opportunity to define the value you'd like to display.

```
public class SortedIdentifier
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SortedIdentifiers : List<SortedIdentifier>
{
    public string SortedIdentifierDisplayValue
    {
        get { return this.FirstOrDefault()?.Name ?? "No Items"; }
    }
}
```

Then use the new class like this:

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "SortedIdentifierDisplayValue";

var list = new SortedIdentifiers { new SortedIdentifier { Name = "John" } };
comboBox1.Items.Add(list);
```