# How to bind a dictionary as a datasource to a ListBox and override the default ToString() of displayMember to display items?

Tags: c#, user-interface, data-binding, listbox

I have Dictionary marketDictionary = new Dictionary(); were MarketDetail contains 4 values/objects. Im trying to use listbox.datasource to display one of the items in MarketDetail for each key.

I can do this fine, but I want to display the item in the `listbox`. What it displays is the key and the name of value MarketDetail. I understand that these are the key pairs I need when selecting `listbox` item.

im using:

```
        listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "key";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "value";
        listBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(marketDictionary, null);
        listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
```

This works perfectly from the point of selecting an item in the list, getting key pair and doing what I need. But is there a way of displaying either my own text for each item added to `listbox` or the value.item from dictionary. I hope this makes sense. regard Robert

Comment: You sure you don't want to switch displaymember and valuemember?

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't get the values in MarketDetail. I can still use the result . Its looks ugly in the listbox though. Is there not a way of still creating a link and displaying my own string? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have a ComboBox DisplayMember set to a property of an object in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58203681/is-it-possible-to-have-a-combobox-displaymember-set-to-a-property-of-an-object-i)

Comment: Thank you for the link. Im quite new at this. regards robert

Answer (score 0):

After lots of reading and testing I found a solution that works for me. I had not realised that when i built the class for my objects in marketDictionary i should have used get/set. 
So i now  link datasource to marketDictionary.Values and i can reference the items in display member. So now i can add a new item in my object class to use for my display member. Perfect. The other thing i have learnt is to use datasource line last, this stopped the selectchange firing.
so now ive got:

```
public class MarketDetail
{
    public string marketId { get; set; }
    public string course { get; set; }
}
      public void myRaceList()
      {
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "course";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "marketId";
        listBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(marketDictionary.Values, null);
      }
```

Comment: Sorry, not sure if ive posted this correctly. Thank you for your replys.